# Rsa algoritmn generates ? characteres in java

Tags: java, android, security, rsa

I'm making an Android app for sending safe sms.
I currently have the following code (Iam using 256 for testing)

```
     public void generateKey() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException,
                IllegalBlockSizeException,BadPaddingException,InvalidKeyException{
            try{
                kpg = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");

                kpg.initialize(256);
                kp = kpg.genKeyPair();

            }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), e.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }

        }
        public byte[] RSAEncrypt(final String plain) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException,
                IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException, InvalidKeyException {
        try {
            publicKey = kp.getPublic();
            privateKey = kp.getPrivate();

            cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, publicKey);
            encryptedBytes = cipher.doFinal(plain.getBytes("UTF-8"));
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),e.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
            return encryptedBytes;
        }
 public void enviaSMS(View view) {
        EditText key = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.publicKey);
        EditText phoneNumber = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.phoneNumber);
        EditText text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.TextMessage);
        String keyText = key.getText().toString();
        String number = phoneNumber.getText().toString();
        String sms = text.getText().toString();
        if (!keyText.equals("") && !number.equals("") && !sms.equals("")) {
            try {

                byte[] encriptedSMS= RSAEncrypt(sms);
                Log.i("teste",new String(encriptedSMS));
                Log.i("teste",new String(encriptedSMS, "UTF-8"));
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), new String(encriptedSMS, "UTF-8"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); // ou send?:3
                SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();

                smsManager.sendTextMessage(number, null, new String(encriptedSMS,"UTF-8"), null, null);

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SMS Sent!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),e.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }
    }
```

when I encript a string like "hello I am john doe" I get something like `2e2??????24sfe??`

I'm making UTF-8 strings so what may be the problem for the corrupted encryption?

Comment: Where do you see 2e2??????24sfe?? in received sms or console?

Comment: console and receiver message box

Comment: how do u know that console and receiver message box are UTF8 enabled?

Comment: Good point, Is there a way to set the default set instead of doing new String(arrayBityes,"UTF-8") ?

Comment: Console by default are not UTF8 enabled, but you can make them through settings, so look for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
new String(encriptedSMS,"UTF-8")
```

Your problem is here. `encriptedSMS` does not contain UTF-8 encoded text, so this is wrong.

*There is no correct way* to "convert" a byte array into a `String`, unless the byte array contains encoded text (like you would get from `someString.getBytes("UTF-8")`).

However, there are ways to encode a byte array as a string. Base64 is one such encoding. Since this is Android, you can use the `android.util.Base64` class:

```
String encodedSMS = Base64.encodeToString(encriptedSMS, Base64.DEFAULT)
```

and to decode it, something like:

```
byte[] encriptedSMS = Base64.decode(encodedSMS, Base64.DEFAULT)
```

Comment: Exactly. Repeat after me. String is not a container for binary data. Write out 100 times.

Comment: Although the decoding still doesn't do what I want, this problem was about the encoding, so thank you